# JavaScript, how to create an object out of an array?

Tags: javascript

I would like to convert an array that looks like this:

```
['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
```

to an object that looks like this:

```
{
  foo: true,
  bar: true,
  baz: true,
}
```

In most languages you would have some form of `fill(keys, value)` function:

```
var array = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
var object = fill(array, true);
// object = { foo: true, bar: true, baz: true}
```

But in JS I can only find one for numeric keys using a range, not a list of keys.
Is there a fill function that will do exactly that?

Comment: No but there's `.reduce()`. (I'm not so sure there's such a `.fill()` method in "most" languages.)

Comment: `Object.fromEntries(array.map(x => [x,true]))`

Comment: ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'].reduce((a, v) => ({ ...a, [v]: true}), {})

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
const data = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
const asObject = Object.fromEntries(data.map(d => ([d, true])))

console.log(asObject)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can build an object with `.reduce()`:

```
var object = array.reduce((o, e) => (o[e] = true, o), {});
```

*edit* — or the clever `Object.fromEntries()` solution mentioned in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't such function as `fill(keys, value)` that you mentioned, but you could also do so:

```js
let tab = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];

let obj = {}

tab.forEach(v=>{obj[v]=true});

console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can map the array values to entries (key, value pairs) and then transform the matrix into an object.

```js
const
  arr = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'],
  obj = Object.fromEntries(arr.map(v => [v, true]));

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new object, loop over the array and add each value to it.

```
let arr = ['foo','bar','baz'];
let obj={};
arr.forEach(el => {obj[el] = true})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.